# Reversing byte order of negative integer with Python 3

Tags: python, byte, bit, 32-bit

After extracting some 32-bit sign bit value and keeping that same 32-bit representation sign-extended, I now have to reverse the byte order of the value (I need to follow a precise imposed workflow).

Here is what I previously did :

- initially I have the value `"11101101111110100111001110011010"`
- I converted that chain to `int` : I get `3992613786`
- I extracted the 32-bit sign bit (sign-extended) : I get `-302353510`

Now, I have to reverse the byte order of that last value (I am supposed to get `-1703675155` in the end).

Does anyone know how to reverse the byte order of a negative extended sign bit with Python3 ?

Comment: https://pythontic.com/modules/socket/byteordering-coversion-functions

Comment: In the proposed document I don't see anything about managing negative values.

Comment: Reversing the byte order just reverses the bytes, why should there be a special handling for negative numbers? If you store the reversed bytes in some signed integer variable, then it will show negative value (if applicable). If you store the reversed bytes in some unsigned integer variable, it will always show some positive (or 0) value.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better ways but this seems to work:

```
from struct import pack

x = "11101101111110100111001110011010"

n = ((~int(x, 2) + 1) & 0xffffffff) * -1 if x[0] == '1' else 1


print(int.from_bytes(pack('!i', n), 'little', signed=True))
```

**Output:**

```
-1703675155
```